# Linux Script to get time in seconds when folder was last modified

Tags: linux, bash, time, directory

I need a linux bash script to know the time in seconds when a particular folder was modified.
Can someone please help me?

My current script below is getting the current time stamp and the last time the folder was modified, but i do not know how to proceed.

```
[root@cgf01 log]# more CheckLastCdr.sh 
#get current timestamp
current_time=`date` 

#get last CDR timestamp
last_cdr_time=`find /tmp/log/ -exec stat \{} --printf="%y\n" \; | sort -n -r | head -1`


echo $current_time
echo $last_cdr_time
```

when i run this script i am getting the following:

```
[root@cgf01 log]# ./CheckLastCdr.sh 
./CheckLastCdr.sh: line 6: 2011-04-05: command not found
Tue Apr 5 16:19:31 CEST 2011
2011-04-05 16:14:33.000000000 +0200
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the number of seconds ago:

```
echo $[$(date +%s)-$(stat --printf "%Y" /tmp/log)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use find to get this info. You can use `stat` like so:

`stat --printf=%Y dirname`

Comment: But `stat` does not recurse, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
find /tmp/log/ -exec stat \{} --printf="%y\n"
```

to:

```
find /tmp/log/ -exec stat \{} --printf="%T@\n"
```